# how to connect volume to docker container in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

my docker-compose file

```
services:
  irc:
    image: inspircd/inspircd-docker
    container_name: irc
    volumes: 
        - ./configs:/inspircd/configs


  app:
    build: ./tor
    container_name: tor
    ports: 
     - 443:443
     - 9001:9001
     - 9030:9030
    links: 
     - irc
    depends_on: 
        - irc

volumes: 
  irc_conf:
    driver: local
    driver_opts: 
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /home/advaithm/irc_docker/configs
```

I don't understand how to mount my configs folder. can someone explain how the correct way to mount them is.  i need to mount configs at /home/advaithm/irc_docker/configs to /inspircd/configs in the container. with just docker i would use `-v /home/advaithm/irc_docker/configs :/inspircd/configs` i would like to no the equivalent in the docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change (host volume):

```
volumes: 
    - ./configs:/inspircd/configs
```

By (named volume):

```
volumes: 
    - irc_conf:/inspircd/configs
```

**Named volumes** can be referred to by **specific names** . You have created the volume by name when you defined it at the bottom.

However, you didn't mount it.

Comment: i need to mount my configs folder to /inspircd/configs